# Error in R code in EM Algorithm from R blogger webpage

Tags: r, algorithm, expectation-maximization

I refer to the EM code from this page:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/imputing-missing-data-with-expectation-maximization/

Initially, when I run the code `raw < - replicate(10, rpois(50,100))`, 
I received this error:

```
Error in raw < -replicate(10, rpois(50, 100)) : 
  comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Then I changed that random data to `raw<-faithful$waiting`.
But subsequently, I received another error:

```
Error in solve.default(sig[!pick.miss, !pick.miss]) : 'a' is 0-diml
```

Is anyone here familiar with this code and how to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when copying code, especially from a low-quality website such as R-Blogger: assignment in R is done by `<-`, *not* by `< -`. The space between the two characters is wrong, you need to remove it.

Generally you can also replace `<-` by `=` to avoid this problem (opinions differ within the R community as to whether `=` or `<-` is preferred for assignment).

Comment: Thank very much you Konrad Rudolph ;)

Comment: @Jas https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619